# Adding buttons to static table view/calling methods from tableview cells

Tags: ios, static, tableview

Quite simply, I'm trying to add multiple buttons to the bottom of the static table view, much like in the address book app (below the contact's details for Send Message, Share Contact and Add to Favourites). However it just simply won't let me add three button in Storyboards unless I use a subview but then I can't quite get the colour to be the same as that of the iOS 6 background (and I've used the colour picker). What happens is that it'll simply add the button below the table view section and it takes up the entire width of the iPad's screen.

My other (and original) thought was to use the static table view cells to simply call methods. What I want to do here is add the building's details (like address, name etc) to the user's contacts app when they press the tableview/button - but I can't link it to any IBActions.

Using a button would be no problem, so if the first issue could be solved that'd be excellent.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the solution with the subview, you can set the views backgroundcolor to [UIColor clearColor]

Comment: Thanks for responding. My bad, even though it shows it as a slightly different colour when using the colour picker, the built application still shows it as normal. This is excellent though, as I can use the buttons. Thanks again